# Agregar evento de click a cada elemento en un stackpanel c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, onclicklistener, mouselistener

Tengo esta lista en stackpanel que se genera sola.

Quiero que al hacer click en la imagen de la flecha con una funcion mandar los datos de ese item a otra funcion que se encargara de almacenarlos y usarlos

[image: Stackpannel]

Con el siguiente codigo:

```
private void addServerCard(string name, string ip, string user, string pass, string status)
    {
        Grid servercard = new Grid();
        servercard.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        //IMAGE SERVER
        Image serverimage = new Image();
        serverimage.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        serverimage.Height = 48;
        serverimage.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
        serverimage.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        serverimage.Width = 48;
        serverimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Resources/principal/Dino.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));


        //LABEL TITULO
        Label servertitle = new Label();
        servertitle.Content = name.ToUpper();
        servertitle.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        servertitle.Margin = new Thickness(63, 10, 0, 0);
        servertitle.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        servertitle.Width = 474;
        servertitle.FontSize = 18;
        servertitle.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        servertitle.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");


        //LABEL DESCRIPCION
        Label serverdesc = new Label();
        if (ip.Equals("127.0.0.1") || ip.Equals("localhost"))
        {
            serverdesc.Content = "SERVIDOR LOCAL - " + status;
        }
        else
        {
            serverdesc.Content = "SERVIDOR REMOTO - " + status;
        }


        serverdesc.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        serverdesc.Margin = new Thickness(63, 41, 0, 0);
        serverdesc.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        serverdesc.Width = 474;
        serverdesc.FontSize = 10;
        serverdesc.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;

        //IMAGE EDIT
        Image serveredit = new Image();
        serveredit.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        serveredit.Height = 48;
        serveredit.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 10, 0);
        serveredit.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        serveredit.Width = 48;
        serveredit.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Resources/principal/arrow-right.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));


        //IMAGE CONNECT
        Image serverconnect = new Image();
        serverconnect.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        serverconnect.Height = 48;
        serverconnect.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 70, 0);
        serverconnect.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        serverconnect.Width = 48;
        serverconnect.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Resources/principal/editar-informacion.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        serverconnect.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

        //GRID DIVIDER
        Grid divider = new Grid();
        Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF1F1F1F");
        divider.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        divider.Margin = new Thickness(0, 64, 0, 0);
        divider.Height = 6;

        


        servercard.Children.Add(serverimage);
        servercard.Children.Add(servertitle);
        servercard.Children.Add(serverdesc);
        servercard.Children.Add(serveredit);
        servercard.Children.Add(serverconnect);
        servercard.Children.Add(divider);

        ServersContainerCards.Children.Add(servercard);
    }
```

Quiero hacer que cada imagen de flecha tenga su propia accion al hacer click en ella, para asi saber cual se presiono y proceder a la siguiente parte del programa con los valores correspondientes.

por ejemplo en java usaba:

```
salir.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            salirMouseEntered(evt);
        }
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            salirMouseExited(evt);
        }
        public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            salirMouseReleased(evt);
        }
    });
```

Y de esa forma cada uno tiene su propio codigo de click en el, pero en C# no encuentro la forma.

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Debes añadir un evento a la hora de crear cada tarjeta. Si quieres por ejemplo que sea al pulsar `serverconnect`, pues deberias hacer algo como `serverconnect.MouseDown+= (aa,bb) => {codigoquequieres ejecutar}`